# Show / hide div on page load depending on radio button value - Jquery and Ruby on Rails Simple Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Jquery with Ruby on Rails and the Simple Form Gem I can successfully show / hide a div on changing a radio button, however despite numerous attempts I can't get this to work on page load - divs are always showing, whether the radio button is true or false. Any help would be great thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('[name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]"]').on('change', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == 'true' ) {
      jQuery('#denied-quote-one').hide();
    } else {
      jQuery('#denied-quote-one').show();
   }
  });
});
```

UPDATE - HTML OUTPUT OF RADIO BUTTONS:

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional user_nurse_qualified">
   <input type="hidden" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" value="">
     <span class="radio">
        <label for="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_true">
            <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" id="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_true">Yes
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="radio">
        <label for="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_false">
           <input class="radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" id="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_false">No
        </label>
       </span>
   </div>

  <div id="denied-quote-one" style="display: block;">
    <p class="p-red">Unfortunately we cannot give you a quote if your answer to this question is no. You will not be able to move forward.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: This code is only fired on `change` event of the radio button

Comment: I know but my question is, how do I make it fire on page load? I tried pageload in place of change and it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above adds an event handler for the `change` event on the radio button.  Aside from that, you need to check the value of the `:checked` radio button on page load, and show/hide based on that.

Note:  To prevent flickering, give the element an initial style of `display: none`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 if ( jQuery('[name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]"]:checked').val() !== 'true' ) {
  jQuery('#denied-quote-one').show();
 }
   
   jQuery('[name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]"]').on('change', function() {
     if (jQuery(this).val() == 'true' ) {
        jQuery('#denied-quote-one').hide();
     } else {
        jQuery('#denied-quote-one').show();
     }
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional user_nurse_qualified">
   <input type="hidden" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" value="">
     <span class="radio">
        <label for="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_true">
            <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" id="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_true">Yes
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="radio">
        <label for="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_false">
           <input class="radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" name="user[nurse_attributes][qualified]" id="user_nurse_attributes_qualified_false">No
        </label>
       </span>
   </div>

  <div id="denied-quote-one" style="display: none;">
    <p class="p-red">Unfortunately we cannot give you a quote if your answer to this question is no. You will not be able to move forward.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd actually tried what you mentioned before but on page load the div is still showing, thought it must of been something wrong with my code at the time. Maybe it's something else causing it? Will continue to look into it.

Comment: On page load it doesn't seem to register the true value, very strange.

Comment: Can you post the radio button HMTL?

Comment: Added to my question

Comment: Updated my answer - You want the value of the radio button that is `:checked`